# What is a Heaviside rational current element?

Tags: electromagnetism

This terminology seems to be referred to a notion invented in an old book of Oliver Heaviside [1]. What is it and why the Biot-Savart law is not unique unless it is applied to a Heaviside rational current element as claimed in this paper [2]? Moreover, why such direct-current element is a physical impossibility?

[1] Oliver, Heaviside. Electrical Papers, Vol.2, Article 48. 1892
[2] Hammond, P. "Electric and magnetic images." Proceedings of the IEE-Part C: Monographs 107, no. 12 (1960): 306-313.